# Is slicing a dangerous operation in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, numpy

I am reading the [Ndarray documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) in Python and it has the following example.

> A 2-dimensional array of size 2 x 3, composed of 4-byte integer
>   elements:
>
> ```
> >>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
> >>> type(x)
> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
> >>> x.shape
> (2, 3)
> >>> x.dtype
> dtype('int32')
> ```
>
> The array can be indexed using Python container-like syntax:
>
> ```
> >>> # The element of x in the *second* row, *third* column, namely, 6.
> >>> x[1, 2]
> ```
>
> For example slicing can produce views of the array:
>
> ```
> >>> y = x[:,1]
> >>> y
> array([2, 5])
> >>> y[0] = 9 # this also changes the corresponding element in x
> >>> y
> array([9, 5])
> >>> x
> array([[1, 9, 3],
>        [4, 5, 6]])
> ```

I have a MATLAB background, and when we do `y = x[:, 1]`, `y` becomes a distinct 2x1 matrix, after which changing any element of `y` produces no change in the original matrix `x`. However, it seems that in Python changing the elements of `y` does alter the original array `x`.

Can someone comment on whether this operation should be avoided? Because I don't want to accidentally change my original data by operating on some parts of the data.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code, post your code as formatted text

Comment: You may use `.copy()` as `y = x[:, 1].copy()`

Comment: It is just a view into the array, so changing parts in the view reflects on the source. Try copying it over.

Comment: python list is mutable, you must be careful when pass it as a parameter or just assign it. There are also some other mutable types, dict, set etc.

Comment: At first this freaks everyone out but you will get used to it.

Comment: @LeeHoYo The phenomenon the OP is talking about has nothing to do with lists, and indeed lists _don't_ behave the same way as NumPy arrays with respect to slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slice in a numpy array is a view of the object (unlike a slice in a list which will return a new object), which means the values you get back are a reference to the original array. Quoted from the article [Views versus copies in NumPy](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html), emphasis mine:

> What is a view of a NumPy array?
>
> As its name is saying, it is simply another way of viewing the data of the array. Technically, that means that the data of both objects is shared. You can create views by selecting a slice of the original array, or also by changing the dtype (or a combination of both). These different kinds of views are described below.
>
> Slice views
>
> This is probably the most common source of view creations in !NumPy.
>   The rule of thumb for creating a slice view is that **the viewed
>   elements can be addressed with offsets, strides, and counts in the
>   original array**. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> a = numpy.arange(10)
> >>> a
> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
> >>> v1 = a[1:2]
> >>> v1
> array([1])
> >>> a[1] = 2
> >>> v1
> array([2])
> ```

When you use a slice because you want to look at part of the data or apply operations on them which are **not** done in-place, it's completely safe. If you expect to modify the data in-place, then you want to create a new copy of the elements with `np.copy()`

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 3, 1, 8, 5])
>>> b = a[1:5]
>>> b
array([5, 3, 7, 2])
>>> # this will create a new array and sort it
>>> np.sort(b)
array([2, 3, 5, 7])
>>> b
array([5, 3, 7, 2])
>>> # this is done in-place, which means it will also affect `a`
>>> b.sort()
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 1, 8, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely the correct behaviour for Python. One of the greatest benefits of the language is that everything is passed as a reference rather than values. If you really want to create a new matrix from the slice, consider the `.copy` method.

Comment: Python's argument passing conventions and simple assignment semantics don't really have much to do with slicing semantics. Consider that if `y` is a plain old Python list (of length 4, say), and `x = y[2:]`, then modifying `x` does _not_ alter `y`. The OP is noting that isn't true for NumPy arrays.